# Pycharm Python3 Flask Module not Found Error

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm a fairly new programmer I installed flask through pip and was trying to run it in Pycharm, it wouldn't work, so I downloaded Flask 1.02 on Pycharm, it then gave me some error messages which I will include in some pictures. This has been driving me crazy, if anyone can help me fix this I would truly appreciate it!

[Error message!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMfmr.png)

Edit these are the error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Farhan/PycharmProjects/Helloworld/fuck_you.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/Users/Farhan/PycharmProjects/Helloworld/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/Users/Farhan/PycharmProjects/Helloworld/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "/Users/Farhan/PycharmProjects/Helloworld/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 67, in <module>
    from werkzeug._internal import _get_environ
  File "/Users/Farhan/PycharmProjects/Helloworld/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/_internal.py", line 30, in <module>
    string.digits +
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_letters'
```

Comment: Please add the errors to your question in text form, not as images

Comment: Oh, ok Sorry will do

Comment: you are actually running a file named fuck_you in the given screenShot. Show us the code in this file

Comment: from flask import Flask, that's all the code that I was running, just to see if it would run, but I got the same error message that I posted earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer! So, I previously tried to install flask on the virtualenv on pycharm before, but this time I created a new file and a new project within that file, and reinstalled flask on Pycharm with pip install flask, and surprisingly it worked.